# Reference for etale cohomology on stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Is there good reference for general theory.of etale cohomology on stacks and more advanced topics?
Thanks

Comment: @ArunDebray Unfortunately, the etale cohomology chapter of the stacks project http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03N1 covers only schemes, and the cohomology of stacks chapter http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/073P covers only sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules.

Comment: You can look at "Champs algébriques" by Laumon & Moret-Bailly for a discussion of the lisse-etale site and it's cohomology, and also some papers of Olsson which fixed problems with this. I'll let experts comment further if they want.

Comment: that is written in French, may not be convenient.

Comment: You can try looking at the series of papers by Laszlo and Olsson.

Comment: The L-(M-B) book has a serious error, and does not address some of the fundamental theorems of etale cohomology which are proved via Chow's lemma (e.g. proper base change). Look at Olsson's paper "Sheaves on Artin Stacks" [https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/qcohrevised.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/qcohrevised.pdf) for an updated treatment that fixes this error, treats some more recent developments, and moreover is in English.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the stomach for technical stuff, I highly recommend the treatment in Gaitsgory-Lurie's article on Tamagawa numbers over function fields:

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/tamagawa-abridged.pdf

This is section 3.2 and everything is actually done from scratch.